# span i class font awesome before after width 100px

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to set width in span class before or after to be set into my code accordingly. I highly appreciate your help to guide me how to make it done.

**Here is my code in PHP:**

```
<div class="list-inline route-list-plane" >
<?php echo $module->from; ?>
<span class="plane-icon-wrapper"><i  class="fa fa-plane plane-icon"></i></span>
<?php foreach($package_location as $loc) { ?>
<span><?php echo $loc->location; ?></span>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

**and here is my CSS and HTML code based on above PHP code:**

```css
.route-list-plane {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background: #0097d6;
}
.plane-icon-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 12px 0 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.plane-icon {
    -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
    transform: rotate(225deg);
    -moz-animation: plane 5s infinite;
    -o-animation: plane 5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: plane 5s infinite;
    animation: plane 5s infinite;
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    padding: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes plane {

    0% {
        right: 0px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    25% {
        right: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
        transform: rotate(225deg);
    }
    50% {
        right: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    75% {
        right: 0;
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    100% {
        right: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
        transform: rotate(225deg);
    }
}

@keyframes plane {

    0% {
        right: 0px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    25% {
        right: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
        transform: rotate(225deg);
    }
    50% {
        right: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    75% {
        right: 0;
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    100% {
        right: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
        transform: rotate(225deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="list-inline route-list-plane">
Koln<span class="plane-icon-wrapper"><i class="fa fa-plane plane-icon"></i></span>
<span>Kuala Lumpur</span>
<span>Singapore</span>
<span>Bali</span>
</div>
```

I want to set animated moving plane between cities. how can I set width between cities in before or after span ?

**

> As you can see plane-icon-wrapper class is set to 100px that's why
>   plane is moving correctly, but this width is not set between cities
>   based on span before/after, and moving plane is also not there. how to
>   set it correctly?
>   I mean **between ((Kuala Lumpur - Singapore)) and between ((Singapore - Bali))**

**

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you add class "col-md-12" to your element   where you need 100% width?

Comment: 100% width not in bootstrap. please read the question, 100% width in before/after in plane-icon-wrapper class where plane is moving!

Comment: In your snippet everything is working just fine, so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: As you can see plane-icon-wrapper class is set to 100% that's why plane is moving correctly, but this width is not set between cities based on span before/after, and moving plane is also not there. how to set it correctly?

Comment: I still don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I mean between ((Kuala Lumpur - Singapore)) and between ((Singapore - Bali))

Comment: your `plane-icon-wrapper` is set to `100px` _not_ `100%`, are you trying to add a second and third plane between your other `span`s?

Comment: Yes this is what I want. please guide me how to add it moving plane between other cities based on span before/after in the css and based on my php code. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the span with class="plane-icon-wrapper" inside the foreach loop

```
<div class="list-inline route-list-plane" >
<?php echo $module->from; ?>
<?php foreach($package_location as $loc) { ?>
<span><?php echo $loc->location; ?></span><span class="plane-icon-wrapper"><i  class="fa fa-plane plane-icon"></i></span>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You guided me to the right path, I added another span after div now it's working. thanks a lot